How tall and how dense can an electric Reel Mower with a max speed of 1500rpm and torque of 4.2 Nm cut?
What happens if you use an electric reel mower with an RPM of 1500 rpm and torque of 4.2Nm. will a Reel mower be able to cut thick and dense grasses/weeds?
